# how to change type in python dictionary in function?

Tags: python, c++

I have a really large group of pandas dataframe.
and transfer own column from json format string to dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(XXXX)
df = pd.read_sql(balabal).to_dict(orient='records')
```

After we get dictionary, we need transfer one entity says df[0]['paragraphs'] from string to dictionary. Here is the code. i['t'] is key and i['p'] is value.

```
import json
def str2dict(input_str):
    j = json.loads(input)
    ret = {}
    for i in j:
        ret[i['t']] = i['p']
    return ret
```

And I call this function by:

```
for i in df:
    i['paragraphs'] = preprocess.str2dict(i['paragraphs'])
```

It works fine. 
but at this part `i['paragraphs'] = preprocess.str2dict(i['paragraphs'])` it did unnecessary copy.
I want my str2dict function be like this:

```
def str2dict(input_str):
    j = json.loads(inputs)
    clear memory where input_str pointed. and let it be a new dictionary
    for i in j:
        input_str[i['t']] = i['p']
```

so that we can reduce the copy assignment.

And I'm confused that
in Python everything is object, so the variable are like shared_pointer in C++.
But where does there object be implement(initialized). 
Does all objects' pointee store in heap, and in stack of function all variable are pointer.

when we do this

```
a = 1
a = {'a':1}
a = 2
```

Python will new a dictionary and let a point to it. 
and when a = 2, program will delete dictionary on heap and point to 2.

but how about in function?

```
def test(a):
    a = {}
    return
s = 1
test(s)
```

s is still 1. I think `a = {}` create a dict and create a local variable a to point it, this a have no relation to parameter a. So how can I use parameter a to let output s = {}.

And in the end, where can I learn how Python implement (where the variable store, what happens when it type changed)and memory staff? I think I should learn something about Cpython. Do you guys have any suggestion about what books or videos should I read? 
thx :)

Answer (score 2):

CPython works very differently from C++. Everything is on the heap. Memory is managed automatically by reference counting (cycles are dealt with a garbage collector). Variables are not typed. Python does not support pass by reference semantics. `i['paragraphs'] = preprocess.str2dict(i['paragraphs'])` does *not* make a copy. If no other reference to the string referenced by `i['paragraphs']` exists, that string's reference count will go to zero once `str2dict` terminates, and the memory will be reclaimed.

This function:

```
def test(a):
    a = {}
    return
```

creates a `dict` object, it gets assigned to the *local name* `a`. Once the function returns, no other references to that `dict` exist, and the `dict` object is deallocated. This is handled by the Python runtime, and generally, you do not worry about these things.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to free RAM while runnig your program?
I am not sure that you can do that,at least not in a way similar to C++.
With CPython you have [gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html)

It says

```
This module provides an interface to the optional garbage collector. It provides the ability to disable the collector, tune the collection frequency, and set debugging options
```

Anyway,gc could reclaim memory but it doesn't necessarily return it to the OS.

Comment: The garbage collector only handles reference cycles. If object reference counts go to zero, they are reclaimed, regardless of whether you enable or disable `gc`

Comment: I want to free a element in dict and reassign it into a new type.